# Get data from multiple table using Entity Framework 5

Tags: linq, entity-framework

In my database, I have 4 tables with relationship like this:

Inspection --> Correspondence --> CorrespondenceTo, User

Now, when `InspectionID` equals something, I want to get `Subject`, `CorrespondenceType`, `SentDate` from `Correspondence`, `DisplayName` from `User`, `FirstName`, `LastName` from `CorrespondenceTo`. So I write code like this:

```
var result = from i in context.Inspections
        join correspondence in context.Correspondences 
            on i.Id equals correspondence.InspectionId
        join correspondenceTo in context.CorrespondenceToes 
            on correspondence.Id equals correspondenceTo.CorrespondenceId
        join user in context.Users 
            on correspondence.SenderUserId equals user.Id

        where i.Id == inspectionID
        select new
        {
            Subject = correspondence.Subject,
            CorrespondenceType = correspondence.CorrespondenceType,
            SentDate = correspondence.SentDate,
            Sender = user.DisplayName,
            Receiver = new
            {
               correspondenceTo.FirstName,
               correspondenceTo.LastName
            }
        };
return Json(result);
```

What's wrong with my code? How to see the result in Visual Studio 2012? Besides, I want to left join all the tables above. What should I do? If I want to use `Include` instead of `Join`, how to do that?

Comment: "What's wrong with my code?" -> What's wrong with your output? What are you expecting, what are you getting?

Comment: why don't you use the Storeprocedure  instead of making it so complex?

Comment: @RohitVyas Because Stored Procs make it MORE complicated not LESS. Have you ever tried "upgrading" a sproc based database interface.

Comment: Could you explain how it isn't working? That should work (perhaps you need to `ToList()` the `result`). But without some context on what this code is running in (I think its an ASP.Net <VC 4 WebAPI controller), I can't tell you how to see the result. Have you managed to run the code with a break point? Can use use the Watch inspector to see the result of this function?

Comment: I think it's something about materialization. `DisplayName` is not a field in database. It's my added property to return `FirstName + LastName` Another one fix my code using Include instead of joining table like me, and it works. Why?